# Strapi disable default login page

Tags: keycloak, single-sign-on, openid-connect, strapi

I have used the library [strapi-plugin-sso](https://github.com/yasudacloud/strapi-plugin-sso) so I can login OIDC with this library but I want to disable the default strapi's default login page is there a way of doing that by middleware or other methods without enterprise license

I want to disable this:
[image]

Or there is away redirect to this (strapi-plugin-sso plugin):
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You could use `yarn patches` to customize your login page.

Comment: Thank you for answering questions here♥️. However, it could be more useful if you describe how exactly that command helps with customizing the login page instead of just showing the command.

Comment: Thank you @Jiang Fan for your answer but could you please help give more specific instructions so that I can follow and fix this issue with this command `yarn patches`